# Plotting data versus clock time

Tags: matlab, datetime, date, plot

I have high resolution data (500 Hz). I started at 12:00:00 p.m.

In total I have 7.2 million data points <7,200,000x1 double> called data. How would I plot it against real time, like 12 pm, 1 pm, 2 pm, 3 pm, 4 pm, etc. (date ticks)

Answer (score 6):

Consider this example:

```
Fs = 500;                                         %# sampling frequency (Hz)
startTime = datenum('12:00:00 PM','HH:MM:SS PM'); %# recording start time
x = cumsum(rand(7200000,1)-0.5);                  %# some random data

t = (0:(numel(x)-1)) ./ Fs;                       %# time in seconds
t = t/3600/24 + startTime;                        %# time in days (serial date)

%# plot
plot(t(1:2000:end), x(1:2000:end))                %# plot every 2000 values
datetick('x','HH:MM:SS PM')
xlabel('Time'), ylabel('Data')
```

[image: screenshot]

The formatting of the date axis tick marks is done using the [DATETICK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datetick.html) function. Read the documentation to learn how to customize the date format.

Note that as you have millions of points, I opted to plot a sub-sample (every 2000 values), but you can easily change that to plot the entire data if you like...